# Which loop does the break statement break?

Tags: python

In below code, which loop does the break statement break?

```
import time, sys
setT = '07:40'
while 1:
    if time.strftime('%I:%M')==setT:
        for mp in str(123):
            print('the time is'+setT)
        print('End')
        break
```

Comment: Horrible code formatting

Comment: break statements normally breaks to the nearest outer loop

Comment: It breaks from the loop containing it. In the code you posted there is only one loop containing a break so that's the loop that breaks.

Comment: Don't vote him down, he is new to python as well as SO

Comment: It breaks the `while` loop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a dump of a homework assignment that shows ZERO effort from the OP.

Comment: @FlyingGambit So what if (s)he's new? (S)He _had_ to read how to ask or follow couple tutorials before dumping a question here.

Comment: @Octo You don't lose reputation on downvoting _questions_.

Comment: Its probably homework I just realised. Re-downvoting.

Comment: @lafexlos really I thought you did

Comment: @Octo You lose 1 reputation if you downvote _an answer_. No loss on questions.

Comment: I believe in welcoming new users and then rectifying their mistakes. Its a mistake only if its done once, but a crime if done twice

Comment: OK my mistake. Anyway question closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any `break` statement always breaks to the nearest outer loop

so in this case, it will break to the `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

After the first `while 1` the loop will break because you have break. So it will print once, and its the while loop that gets broken.